# ContentNegotiatingViewResolver can handle .json bu cannot handle .xml

Tags: xml, json, spring, view, content-negotiation

I am using ContentNegotiatingViewResolver to make .json return a json format data and .xml return a xml format data.
the ContentNegotiatingViewResolver config is like below:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
    <property name="defaultContentType" value="text/html" />
    <property name="favorParameter" value="true"/>
    <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
    <property name="mediaTypes">
        <map>
            <entry key="json" value="application/json" />
            <entry key="xml" value="application/xml" />
        </map>
    </property>

    <property name="defaultViews">
        <list>
            <!-- JSON View -->
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.MappingJackson2JsonView">
            </bean>

            <!-- JAXB XML View -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
                <constructor-arg>
                    <bean class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">
                        <property name= "packagesToScan" value= "com.legjq.jing.model.nosql.sequoiadb" />
                    </bean>
                </constructor-arg>
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>

</bean>
```

When I use id.json, it can return the correct data. log shows:
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor  - Written [****] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" using [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@37771ee5]

But when I use id.xml. it report 406 error The resource identified by this request is only capable of generating responses with characteristics not acceptable according to the request "accept" headers.
log shows:
org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver  - Resolving exception from handler [***]: org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException: Could not find acceptable representation

Is there any step I miss ?